# how to hide navbar from app.component.html and show after login

Tags: angular

In my app.component.html, I have my navigation bar and router-outlet. I want to hide navbar from the login page and show it after login.I used angular-2/jwt helper for checking whether a token is available in the local-storage and I hide the navbar from the login page based on the return value. but after login navbar is not showing
Please help me.Thanks in advance

```js
app.component.ts
================

ngOnInit() { 
  this.authservice.userLoggedIn()
  }



login-service.ts
================


import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  authToken: any[];
  user: any[];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/authenticate',user,{headers:headers})
   
     .map(res=>res.json());
 }
 storeUserData(token,user){
localStorage.setItem('id_token',token);
localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
this.authToken=token;
this.user=user;
 }

  userLoggedIn(){

return tokenNotExpired();
 }

}




login.ts
========

 onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    const user=
    {
      username:form.value.username,
      password:form.value.password
    }
    this.authservice.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.success){
      
        this.invalidlogin=false;
        this.authservice.storeUserData(data.token,data.user)
        this.authservice.userLoggedIn();
        this.router.navigate(['dashboards/dashboard',data.token])
      }
    else{
     this.invalidlogin=true;
     
      // this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
   

    })
  }
```

```html
app.component.html
==================

 <div class="bg-dark" *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&& (layout == 'empty-view-1')"></div>
<sample-modals *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&& (controller == 'notifications' && view == 'modals') "></sample-modals>
<right-sidebar-1 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&&  (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></right-sidebar-1>
<navbar-1 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&& (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></navbar-1>
<top-navigation-1 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&&  (layout == 'top-navigation-1')"></top-navigation-1>
<jumbotron-2 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&&  (layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></jumbotron-2>
<top-navigation-2 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&& (layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></top-navigation-2>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="left-sidebar-placeholder" *ngIf="authservice.userLoggedIn()&&  (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></div>
   <left-sidebar-1 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&& ( layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-2')"></left-sidebar-1> 
   <div class="col main">
    <jumbotron-1 *ngIf=" authservice.userLoggedIn()&& ( controller != 'dashboards' && (layout == 'default-sidebar-1' || layout == 'collapsed-sidebar-1' || layout == 'off-canvas-1' || layout == 'sidebar-over-1' || layout == 'top-navigation-1'))"></jumbotron-1> 
    <div class="page">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<backdrops></backdrops>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEeqY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTF4s.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do for this kind of cases (and to me it looks easier), is this structure

```
AppComponent
LoginComponent
Guarded/
    MainView/
    MainViewComponent
        RandomComponent
```

1. Your AppComponent has a router outlet
2. The default route on that is the LoginComponent
3. Once connected, you send the user to another route, let's say `/connected`, that is guarded
4. This sends the user on the MainViewComponent
5. MainViewComponent has the navbar, and a router outlet
6. The default route is the component you desire.

This way, you have a clear separation of logged/non-logged components, and you don't have to play with conditions to show/hide some of the components in your pages.

Comment: Here is a **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zupaiw?file=app%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html)**

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Also do not forget to add `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }` so it will redirect to home in any other case (this also should be guarded. So you can redirect to login accordingly)

Comment: what if the navbar is a component itself that has to be shown in every page(component) ?!

Comment: @Ianna then you should add it to the root component, which in this case would be the app component

Answer (score 0):

Declare one flag initially set its value false and after login set it true.
And in html set condition (*ngIf="flag == true").